# Discrete measurement - continuous observer design

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control

I have to design a controller for the above system where the two pulse generators (red blocks ) are synchronized (measurements are only available at discrete points). However, my understanding is that the controller and measurements should have faster dynamics than the system in order for it to have good performance, but in my system I cannot increase the measurement sampling alone since its synchronized with the fixed pulse generator (input to system). Can I use an observer to estimate the values between two sampling points of measurements hence provide continuous input to the controller? In other words, can I use both real measurements and estimated ones for the same variable? How can I design the observer in this case? Is there any other possible solution?

[image]

Comment: Hi welcome to engineering. Could you provide a bit more detail about your system output? Is it a continuous or discrete variable? From what  I understand you are taking two sets of measurements (system and sample and hold block)? Are you doing that for comparison purposes or is it part of the pid?

Comment: I would really like some more information regarding the pulse generator blocks (the red ones). I see that the one is connected to the system block. What happens when both of them send a single pulse ?

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem, I think it can be solved on Simulink  (Matlab).